HttpClient PostAsync causes deadlock on await
I'm not entirely sure of what is going on.  When I use the code below and I await the HttpClient I get a deadlock and the response never returns.  If i put the await on await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() then the response will come back, but then I'm unsure of how to use IsSuccessStatusCode
public async Task<string> PostAsyncJSONReadAsString(RESTInformation restInformation, string json)
     {
         var httpClient = GetHttpClient(restInformation);
         var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
         //this line Freezes
         //var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(restInformation.Resource, content);
//edit: i made a comment here because it's not clear enough this is a full working example and this will return
         var response = httpClient.PostAsync(restInformation.Resource, content);
         var resultContent = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         /*if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             return resultContent;
         }*/
         return resultContent;
         /*
         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             return contents;
         }*/
         //else return null;
     }


Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster. You most likely have a .Result where you shouldn't have or are missing a await keyword where you should have.

You are also missing using on the content and response

@Progman nah...
and what's worse is the 3 questions don't even address why it freezes await httpClient.PostAsync(restInformation.Resource, content);

@user1257758 You might want to add a [mcve], which shows the freezes when executed. However, the problem and solution is most likely explained in the linked questions (and the other related questions with the exact same problem).

@Progman i feel like we're talking in circles, because not only is that the minimal, I have the exact line commented out and say //this line Freezes.  How much more minal than that, do you want RESTInformation  which only contains 2 stings?

@user1257758 We cannot see how this method is called and where/how exactly it "freezes". We don't even know, if it is a console application, a WPF application, a WinForms application or even part of a service on a ASP.NET server. This might be relevant because of the possible related task/thread pools. Keep in mind that we don't have your surrounding code. That's why the [mcve] should be "complete" to be able to test it. If the problem is unique and not related to the other linked duplicate questions, this question might get reopened (or other duplicate questions can be found).

@Progman ok... it's an MVC application that's calling a webservice that I don't have exposed publicly because it's locally debugged (hence why i left out what's begin called).  I can see that the method is called in the API because it's running in debug once the code it called and completed I can see that the MVC app doesn't continue.  I literally made the code above so simple that one line can be commented out and the other commented in as it works.  What you're not arguing is you believe the other answers answer the question, they do not.  If you can't uncomment a line of code i can't help u

@Progman i cannot stress enough that your/the supplied duplicate answers do not apply.  If they did the the working example above also wouldn't work.  But at last, can't really help the hall monitor type.

Please show how you use the PostAsyncJSONReadAsString method.

Don't use Task.Result, basically:
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(restInformation.Resource, content);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // ...
    var resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}


I tried, and I couldn't because await PostAsync never returns.
  //this line Freezes
 //var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(restInformation.Resource, content);


ConfigureAwait(false) allows me to use the code, but I don't know udnerstand why it's needed

@user1257758 that suggests to me that some other code in this area - perhaps the code calling this - is also doing a sync-over-async (i.e. calling .Result, .Wait(), or .GetAwaiter().GetResult() rather than using await)
